# Trying to import csv into Sharepoint Online but items never import to list

Tags: powershell

I have been using this script below and it looks like it goes through, however the items never import into the list.  I feel like I am missing something but I'm not sure what.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
$user = "username"

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force

$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $password)

Connect-SPOService -Url https://Your-Company-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $mycreds

Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://Your-Company.sharepoint.com -Credential $mycreds

$Upload = Import-CSV "C:\test1.csv"

foreach ($Record in $Upload) {
    Add-PnPListItem -List "List Name" -Values @{
        "Our_x0020_Staff"                = $Record.'Our Staff';
        "Type_x0020_of_x0020_Ticket"     = $Record.'Type of Ticket';
        "Created"                        = $Record.'Created';
        "Problem"                        = $Record.'Problem';
        "Equipment_x0020_Name"           = $Record.'Equipment Name';
        "Title"                          = $Record.'Title';
        "Location"                       = $Record.'Location';
        "Our_x0020_Team"                 = $Record.'Our Team';
        "Ticket_x0020_Assigned_x0020_To" = $Record.'Ticket Assigned To';
        "Ticket_x0020_Closed_x003f_"     = $Record.'Ticket Closed';
        "Ticket_x0020_Status"            = $Record.'Ticket Status';
        "Solution"                       = $Record.'Solution'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This script works for me.

I have a suspicion that either your `Connect-PnPOnline` url is not correct, or that your value for "List Name" in `Add-PnPListItem` is not correct, or both.

The reason I say this is because if there were other problems wrong with your data, for example if you had the CSV filename wrong or if the data for "created" wasn't in a date format, it would tell you as much in big red words with an error.  Your post seems to imply that you are not receiving an error so I don't think its any problem like that.  However, if you reference a list that is not there or if you are connected to the wrong site, you **will not** receive an error at all.  The command will appear to work even though it doesn't.

Your Connect-PnPOnline url should reference the exact site that this list is on.  For example:
`Connect-PnpOnline -url https://Your-Company-admin.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollectionname`

And double check that the list name in `Add-PnPListItem -List "List Name"` is correct too

Comment: Thanks for your help William!  I made sure to double check, it worked for a one item list but a multiple item list I am receiving this error:                                                                                                                 +     Add-PnPListItem -List "List Name" -Values @{
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPListItem], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.AddListItem

Comment: the error you pasted looks incomplete.  There should be two more lines of error information above it.  Can you include the rest of the error?  Also if you could give me a sample line of data from your CSV file, that would help, so that I can verify the formatting.